# Guidness according JavaFX and OSGI development

Tags: java, javafx, osgi, equinox

I need some guide regarding the development of an OSGI Equinox system with JavaFX as GUI.

What should be the architecture of my system? Any useful materials or tutorials or source code examples?

I looked at e(fx)clipse and frankly didn't get it, so help!!

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

There's a wizard in e(fx)clipse:

- File > New Project ...
- JavaFX > OSGi > OSGi Application Project

which would produce an initial setup of a pure JavaFX + Equinox application from there on you only need your hopefully existing OSGi and JavaFX knowledge. If your application gets more complex you might want to look at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials to see how to use e4+JavaFX

Comment: Thanks man, well i tried it, it created for me !!!!four!!! projects and i don't know what to do, so another help request!!!